# the 1st order jet is closed

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, viscosity-solutions

Given continuous $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \Omega$, define
$$J^{1,+}u(x)=\{p\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid u(x+z)\le u(x)+(p,z)+o(|z|)\},$$
as $z\to 0$. Here $f(z)\le o(|z|)$ means there exists a continuous $\sigma:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that $\sigma(0)=0$ and 
$$ \frac{f(z)}{|z|}\le\sigma(|z|),\quad |z|>0.$$
I want to show $J^{1,+}u(x)$ is closed.

---

Let $p_n\in J^{1,+}u(x)$ such that $p_n\to p$. Then by definition, I need to find continuous $\sigma:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that 
$$
\frac{u(x+z)- u(x)-(p,z)}{|z|}\le \sigma(|z|).\tag{1}
$$

Below is what I have tried:

By assumption, there exists $\sigma_n$ such that for all $n$
$$
\frac{u(x+z)- u(x)-(p_n,z)}{|z|}\le\sigma_n(|z|),\quad |z|>0.
$$
which implies that 
$$
\frac{u(x+z)- u(x)-(p,z)}{|z|}\le |p-p_n|+\sigma_n(|z|).
$$
Using the above inequality, I can show 
$$
\limsup_{z\to 0}\frac{u(x+z)- u(x)-(p,z)}{|z|}\le 0. \tag{2}
$$
But the problem is I don't know how to find a fixed continuous $\sigma$ for $p$ satisfying the requirement (1). Because for $|z|<r$, I can choose $|p_n-p|<r$, but the $\sigma_n$ also changes with $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it. You need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$\frac{u(x+z) - u(x) - (p,z)}{|z|} < \varepsilon$$

whenever $|z|< \delta$. Just choose $n$ large enough so that $|p-p_n| < \varepsilon/2$ and then choose $\delta>0$ so that $\sigma_n(|z|)<\varepsilon/2$ for $|z|< \delta$.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't quite understand it. What you are proving is statement (2) right? But I thought the definition requires me to find a continuous $\sigma$ satisfying the requirement (1). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The standard definition of little-O notation doesn't require $\sigma$ to be continuous. Your notion is equivalent; to see this you just need to show that if $\sigma:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ satisfies $\sigma(0)=0$ and $\sigma$ is continuous at $0$, then you can find some continuous $\hat{\sigma}\geq \sigma$ with $\hat{\sigma}(0)=0$.

Comment: I understand. But how can we get the original function $\sigma$ in your approach? Can we define it as the LHS?

Comment: Yes, or the positive part of left hand side if you want $\sigma$ to be continuous at zero (instead of upper semicontinuous).